dwagent.service (screen) fails after recent Ubuntu 22.04.5 update
We are currently using dwservice.net for IOT RMM. Most IOT units are R-Pi-4b running Ubuntu 22.04.5. All features of dwservice.net were working fine until the recent update. Now the screen app just displays a black square and the mouse. The only fix right now is to install libjack0 and xserver-xorg-video-dummy and load a headless mode xorg.conf. This breaks our processes and is not an acceptable workaround.
In identifying the display related changes in the latest Ubuntu updates. DWService, unfortunately has absolutely ZERO support even for paying customers. I have run exhaustive tests and am fully aware of all the documented display fixes on their documentation site. This is something new and I am confident it is a change in Ubuntu that was released in the last 10 days.

You've provided few specifics; you mention a 22.04.5 update; but that update occurred more than two months ago? Normal updates are package specific, so if you have access to a machine you can explore the logs and see what changed; as we're limited to details you provide and you've indicated 22.04.5 or an late-August; first week Sept change? If you have many machines impacted, contrast package installs between them, and if one isn't you'll have specific package updates to explore. Your details currently are just too vague.

Did you not see that I s aid it happened in the last 10 days? Again I am running an ARM64 edition of Ubuntu 22.04.5 and I experience updates almost weekly. Not sure how you determining my update was a month ago. Is there a log I can generate for you so that you can show me I have not had any updates inn the last ten days? Also we re-imaged the R-Pi and disabled updates and that version is working fine on dwservice.net. Also, I would be happy to share the device with you if you have a dwservice account and you can take a look at it directly. Thank you again in advance for you expertise.

You mention release (22.04.5) and do say 10 days, but without specifics how can I know what you're running. Depending what 22.04 you installed; your machines could be using different kernel stacks (as different ISOs/install media use different defaults) and you've not been specific beyond release; different packages have different updates, so some installs will have received kernel upgrades whilst others won't have. The only clear detail you mention is 22.04.5 update or 10-Sept-24 (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_12ubuntu4.7/changelog)
